# Object reference changing original object

Tags: kotlin

```
class Adult: Resident {
    constructor(name: String, id:String): super(name, id)
    var email: String? = null
    var address: MutableList<String>? = null

    fun setAddress(s: String){
        address = s.split("\\n".toRegex()).toMutableList()
    }

}
```

and it's failing this test case, because when

`b.address = a.address`, `b.address?.add("Universe"`) is being added to object `a` as well.

```
fun test6() {
    val a = Adult("Roger Widdoff","604119274")
    val b = Adult("Kathleen Craig","647022192")
    a.setAddress("123 Main Street\nAnytown, Country")
    assertEquals(2,a.address?.size)

    b.address = a.address

    b.address?.add("Universe")

    assertEquals(3,b.address?.size)

    assertEquals(2,a.address?.size)
}
```

I'm really confused on why this is happening and I've searched documentation for hours. Can anyone link me somewhere to figure this out? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `b.address = a.address` you’re creating a variable that points to an existing object instance (see it as a pointer to the memory where it’s stored). It’s not creating a copy. As a result, you have two variables, `b.address` and `a.address` that point to the same object, an instance of `MutableList<String>`. Any change made to this instance, regardless of which variable you use, will be seen in both of them.

This is not a “feature” of Kotlin, it’s a general concept which is described as [Aliasing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)):

> In computing, aliasing describes a situation in which a data location in memory can be accessed through different **symbolic names** in the program. Thus, *modifying the data through one name implicitly modifies the values associated with all aliased names*, which may not be expected by the programmer.

Normally I’d recommend to change the type of your list to readonly `List`, which would have avoided this buggy test case in the first place. Since you’re not able to modify the test case, you could handle the problem with a custom getter that creates the copy of your list:

```
var address: MutableList<String>? = null
    get () = field?.toMutableList()
```

Comment: so do i need to override the get or set function or something in my adult class? thank you for your explanation for why this is occurring by the way.

Comment: You should not use MutableList in the first place, change it to List, and then you could do b.address = a.address.toList() which will copy the list

Comment: I'm not able to change the test cases.

Comment: Ok well then you should probably override the get to return a copy of your list

Comment: With that code snippet you gave me, now b isnt getting changed at b.add() however it did stop a from being affected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "copy" on `b.address = a.address` you should avoid using the `mutableList`. Instead go with the `immutable` one:

```
class Adult {
    constructor(name: String, id: String)

    var email: String? = null
    var address: List<String> = emptyList()

    fun setAddress(s: String) {
        address = s.split("\\n".toRegex()).toMutableList()
    }
}


class AdultTest {
    @Test
    fun test6() {
        val a = Adult("Roger Widdoff","604119274")
        val b = Adult("Kathleen Craig","647022192")
        a.setAddress("123 Main Street\nAnytown, Country")
        assertEquals(2,a.address.size)

        b.address = a.address

        b.address += "Universe"

        assertEquals(3,b.address.size)
        assertEquals(2,a.address.size)
    }
}
```

Here you have your `address` as immutable list. Copying it with `b.address = a.address` at first just points to the same list. But `b.address += "Universe"` then only changes the list of `b`

Comment: Thank you. I am not able to change the test case however.